# How can I disable compression for specific user agents in IIS6?

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis-6, compression

I'm seeing some problems with IE6 (pre SP2) that seem to be related to http compression. I'd like to disable http compression just for those users. Any suggestions?

Something along the [lines of this](http://sebduggan.com/posts/ie6-gzip-bug-solved-using-isapi-rewrite) might work (but for IIS, not Apache).

Comment: Seems to be true: http://www.dojotoolkit.org/gzip-compression-and-ie6

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[ISAPI Rewrite](http://www.isapirewrite.com/) runs on IIS 6.0, so the solution on that page you linked, should work:

> Simply add the following lines to the
>   global rules file (httpd.conf in your
>   ISAPI_Rewrite installation directory):

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP:User-Agent} MSIE\ [56]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:User-Agent} !SV1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(css|js)$
RewriteHeader Accept-Encoding: .* $1
```

If you don't want to spend 99 USD for the license (I think it's worth, I used it myself on IIS 6.0), there is an [open source project on CodePlex](http://www.codeplex.com/IIRF), which works in a similar way.

Comment: I guess I saw references to HTTP.conf and *assumed* apache. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

That link you referred to IS for IIS.  ISAPI_Rewrite is an ISAPI filter for IIS used for URL rewrites (ala Apache's mod_rewrite).  It should do the trick for you.

[**ISAPI_Rewrite**](http://www.isapirewrite.com/) is very inexpensive and has a free lite version as well.  The majority of mod_rewrite rules will port straight into ISAPI_Rewrite.

An alternative that is completely free, albeit it a bit harder to get set up, is [**Ionic's ISAP Rewrite**](http://www.codeplex.com/IIRF).  There are subtle differences in the rule interpreter so you'll have to do some minor tweaking.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do the same thing in [IIRF](http://iirf.codeplex.com), which is free.  The rule is slightly different than the one used in ISAPI_Rewrite.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} MSIE
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (?!SV1)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  \.(css|js)$
RewriteHeader Accept-Encoding:  .*   $1
```

There's [a video showing how to set up and configure IIRF](http://www.youtube.com/user/pluginseo#play/all/uploads-all/1/gvIE4SDVKl4) (Ionic's ISAPI Rewrite).  It's pretty simple.

Answer (score 0):

Can someone give me this example in APACHE and including swift files.
My guess is:-
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP:USER_AGENT} ^MSIE\ [56]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:User-Agent} ^!SV1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.(css|js|swf)$
RewriteHeader Accept-Encoding:  ^.* $1

But doesnt seem to work